# Library for deep learning on Amazon EC2 with CPU and GPU support for convolutional neural network

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, theano, deep-learning, caffe

I want to train a CNN on a bunch of images. I want to run it on Amazon EC2 CPU or GPU clusters. For running deep learning on a cluster, I figured that some of the options are:

1. h2o (with Spark)
2. Caffee
3. Theano

I am not sure which of these options suit my needs. I read through [h2o documentation on deep learning](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-shannon/25/docs-website/h2o-docs/index.html#Data%20Science%20Algorithms-Deep%20Learning-Introduction), they do not seem to support CNNs. Any ideas on how I should proceed?

Another side question: 
How do I upload my images to the cluster for training the CNN? I am fairly new to cluster computing.

Comment: Another option you should be considering is [torch7](http://code.madbits.com/wiki/doku.php)

Comment: Yes that is an option too. I added a comment to @eickenberg 's answer below. Do you have any comments on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the instructions here https://github.com/deeplearningparis/dl-machine then you can set up an AMI image with Theano and Torch. There is also a PR on the config to have caffe by default as well (if you need it, just checkout the branch and run the install script as soon as the instance is up).

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out. I have not seen people use the EC2 cpu clusters for training CNNs. All of them use the GPU nodes. Is there a specific reason behind this? Is there a good resource which shows that cpu clusters will always be slower compared to gpu clusters in training the CNNs on EC2?

Comment: @PrathameshMKulkarni in my experience, depending on your GPU and model you can get speed ups of x10 and even more, so there's no reason to train on CPU nodes

Comment: Thanks! I will try Caffe. Do you know if there are any libraries which can train a single model across multiple GPUs? This will, for example, help me to take full advantage of the g2.8.xlarge instance on EC2

Answer (score 2):

Just came accross your question. In this **[tutorial](http://vict0rsch.github.io/2016/12/03/aws_gpu/)** you'll also find how to set up an Amazon instance with a GPU to run Deep Learning frameworks.

The AMI (~computer model) is pre-configured with:

> - Ubuntu Server 16.04 as OS
> - Anaconda 4.2.0 (scientific Python distribution)
> - Python 3.5
> - Cuda 8.0 (“parallel computing platform and programming model”, used to send code to the GPU)
> - cuDNN 5.1 (Cuda’s library for Deep Learning used by Tensorflow and Theano)
> - **Tensorflow 0.12** for Python 3.5 and GPU-enabled
> - **Keras 1.1.2** (use with Tensorflow backend)

I believe you can use this set-up with [elastic GPUs](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/ec2/Elastic-GPUs/) to scale the system according to your needs or use a [P2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/en/ec2/instance-types/p2/)

Anyway you can follow the tutorial and use another AMI like [Amazon's Deep Learning AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/amazon-ai/amis/)

Answer (score 1):

AWS provides the Deep Learning AMI with various Deep Learning Frameworks installed into it, which covers your use case since it has Theano as well as Caffe.
Link to Deep Learning AMI https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/amis/.

> How do I upload my images to the cluster for training the CNN? I am
> fairly new to cluster computing?

There are many AWS storage services which gives you way to store your training data (images) which will be accessible to your cluster. Few of them are

1. S3
2. EBS
3. EFS

   Explore them and see what works best for you.